# Some program windows in Windows 8 on macbook pro has small text size

Tags: bootcamp, macbook-pro, windows

On Retina Macbook Pro I am running Windows 8.1 via Bootcamp on Macbook pro

Here is my DPI options(default):

[image]

But some windows showing incorrectly or with a small text size or icons:

[image]

Also I am experiencing similar issues with some other programs

Is there any way to fix hat?

Comment: Is it a retina MacBook Pro?

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler yep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically it is happening when program is not adapted to run in high DPI screens.

High DPI explained:

- [Windows 8.1 - High DPI](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-62-Windows-81-High-DPI)
- [Resolution explained (pixels, DPI, inches)](http://www.pptxtreme.com/help/softshadow/ResolutionExplainedPixelsDPIInches.html)
- [High DPI Settings in Windows](http://www.kynosarges.org/WindowsDpi.html)